# Python MemoryError when running ArcGIS Python Toolbox tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox, memoryerror

I have a [Python Toolbox (.pyt)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000022000000) containing a single tool. Part of that tool is the following function, which creates a dictionary from an attribute table, where the keys are the rows' OBJECTIDs and the values are pulled from a field specified when calling the function. The attributes are accessed with a generator based on an `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`.

```
def make_oid_dict(fc, value_field):
    describe = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    key_field = describe.OIDFieldName
    key_value_pairs = (row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (key_field, value_field)))
    oid_dict = dict(key_value_pairs)
    return oid_dict
```

I want to use the dictionary to access attribute values of the feature IDs in a [Near Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001n000000). I've been trying to run the tool, but every time it calls this function -- for a point feature class with about 1.25 million rows and a `value_field` that is formatted as a Long integer -- it fails with a Python `MemoryError`.

I have successfully called the function on the same feature class from the Python window in ArcCatalog, so I have no idea why it wouldn't be working from within the Python toolbox. The resultant dictionary isn't even that large: just 24 MB, according to `sys.getsizeof()`.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

---

**Edit 1:** I've updated the function to use a dictionary comprehension as follows, per Jason Scheirer's suggestion, but that unfortunately has not solved the `MemoryError` issue.

```
def make_oid_dict(fc, value_field):
    describe = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    key_field = describe.OIDFieldName
    oid_dict = {row[0]: row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (key_field, value_field))}
    return oid_dict
```

---

**Edit 2:** This is an update to clarify the solution(s).

My `make_oid_dict()` function works for me without throwing a `MemoryError` *if and only if* the tool is run using background processing (i.e. by setting `self.canRunInBackground = True` in the tool's `__init__` method). Thanks to Aaron for pointing me in this direction.

In the case that the tool needs to run in foreground processing mode, however, Jason Scheirer's `make_oid_array()` function will run successfully -- or at least it did for me.

Comment: Have you tried running the tool in a 64-bit background geoprocessing environment?

Comment: @Aaron no, I hadn't tried it with 64-bit background geoprocessing because my IT dept. hasn't installed that package for me. However, I switched the tool from foreground processing to (32-bit) background processing and the `MemoryError` has miraculously vanished. WTF, Esri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if switching to a dicitonary comprehension would help:

```
def make_oid_dict(fc, value_field):
    key_field = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (key_field, value_field)) as cur:
        oid_dict = { row[0]: row[1] for row in cur }
    return oid_dict
```

And if you're still running out of memory, try recasting the value back to `int` (`long` in Python can use up a lot more memory):

```
def make_oid_dict(fc, value_field):
    key_field = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (key_field, value_field)) as cur:
        oid_dict = { row[0]: int(row[1]) for row in cur }
    return oid_dict
```

Another alternative, which may not benchmark as fast, would be to use the `array` module. Note that this approach *will not* support sparseley populate values. That is, if you have a table with OIDs [1, 2, 3, 5] the entry for the OID 4 will also be included as a value.

```
def make_oid_array(fc, value_field):
    oid_array = array.array('L')
    key_field = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (key_field, value_field)) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            oid, value = row
            if oid > len(oid_array) - 1:
                oid_array.extend((0 for x in xrange(oid + 1 - len(oid_array))))
            oid_array[oid] = int(value)
    return oid_array
```

This data structure will not be nearly as efficient while looping through the cursor, but will represent itself in memory more efficiently. A numpy array would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately neither of these things is preventing the `MemoryError`.

Comment: Added one more suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I can confirm that `make_oid_array()` works (after I made a couple corrections) in foreground processing. As I noted in a comment to my question, I can also get `make_oid_dict()` to work if I enable background processing for the tool.